# Issue on updating line item of journal entry on Netsuite using suite talk API

Tags: c#, asp.net, netsuite, suitetalk

I am updating journal entry on Net suite using suite talk API.
I can add new lines for the record. but on updating existing line using line ID in am getting below error.

***You do not have permissions to set a value for element line.line due to one of the following reasons: 1) The field is read-only; 2) An associated feature is disabled; 3) The field is available either when a record is created or updated, but not in both cases*.**

i can update lines using GUI but not using API

```
NetSuiteServiceBridge  nsServiceBridge = NetSuiteServiceBridge.serviceInstance;
            JournalEntry j = new JournalEntry();
            //j.subsidiary =new RecordRef {internalId="2",type=RecordType.subsidiary };
           j.internalId = "115939";
            JournalEntryLineList jl = new JournalEntryLineList();

            JournalEntryLine line1 = new JournalEntryLine();         
            line1.startDate = DateTime.Now;
            line1.startDateSpecified = true;
            line1.line = 5;
             line1.lineSpecified = true;
            line1.account = new RecordRef { internalId = "206", type = RecordType.account };
            line1.department = new RecordRef { internalId = "1", type = RecordType.department };
            line1.credit = 100;
            line1.creditSpecified = true;

            jl.line = new JournalEntryLine[] {line1};           
            jl.replaceAll = false;
            j.lineList = jl;

           WriteResponse r= nsServiceBridge.UpdateRecords(j);
```

Answer (score 0):

Web Services has its own permissions separate the the native GUI

This is by design

Comment: Thanks for your response, I have checked for permissions but didn’t find any setting regarding this. Can you help me to know from where i can allow these permissions